# Not able to resolve IP address for eth1 in Vagrant VM

Tags: ip, ipv6, ifconfig

On runnning `ifconfig` command I get the following as output. I need the IP address of `eth1` for running my python server port with.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:CE:08:3D
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fece:83d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2474 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1511 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:204674 (199.8 KiB)  TX bytes:158605 (154.8 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:18:CF:85
          inet6 addr: **fe80::a00:27ff:fe18:cf85/64** Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20998 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1648690 (1.5 MiB)  TX bytes:10524 (10.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet6 addr: fe80::1/128 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:340 (340.0 b)  TX bytes:515 (515.0 b)
```

`inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe18:cf85/64` for `eth1` is not in standard IP addres format. What do I do to get the IP address of `eth1`

**edit 1**: 
Result of the `ip` command:

```
[root@localhost config]# ip a l dev eth1
eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:18:cf:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe18:cf85/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fe80::/64` is a ipv6 address reserved to [Link-local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6). `ip a l dev eth1` should be enough to show your ip address on this specific interface(if assigned or acquired through a dhcp-server).

**Worth reading**:

- [Why is fe80::/10 reserved for link local addresses when fe80::/64 is actually used?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130/why-is-fe80-10-reserved-for-link-local-addresses-when-fe80-64-is-actually-us)
- [Where is the statement of deprecation of ifconfig (on linux)? - best answer](https://serverfault.com/a/633089/122772)
- [IPv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address)

Comment: ip a l dev eth1 gave the following as output but no IP address - http://pastie.org/10002581

Comment: I am looking for the **inet addr** parameter in specific of eth1.

Comment: @Sashank please add your pastie to the Question itself.

Comment: Have you ever acquired or set an ip address on this interface? Try the following test: `ip link set dev eth1 up`, `ip addr add 192.168.1.10/24 dev eth1` , `ip a l dev eth1`.  It shall list a ipv4 address. You could use the following commands to check link status on your interface: `ethtool eth1 | grep Link`

Comment: Thanks! :) That was helpful. Sorry, but I am a noob in the area.

Comment: No need to fell ashamed :)